# Marquee start in center to the left

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, marquee

I am looking for a way to start the `marquee` (text slider) from the center to the left.

Because if I reload my page, marquee is blank.

Comment: Post your website or better: your code; and state what you’ve tried so far.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c9pqt94g/ Try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that [`marquee` is obsolete in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#the-marquee-element-0), and [its events aren't well-supported](http://help.dottoro.com/ljlhqxbo.php).

That said, one way would be using `text-indent`, but it makes it scroll slightly shifted. To workaround that you could reduce its property slowly on a `setInterval`. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9pqt94g/2/), or run the following snippet:

```js
var textIndentPercent = 50;
var marqueeCenteringInterval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('my-marquee'));
    console.log(textIndentPercent);
    console.log(document.getElementById('my-marquee').style.textIndent);
    document.getElementById('my-marquee').style.textIndent = -textIndentPercent + '%';
    textIndentPercent -= 0.1;
    if (textIndentPercent < 0) {
        document.getElementById('my-marquee').style.textIndent = '0px';
        clearInterval(marqueeCenteringInterval);
    }
}, 100);
```

```html
<marquee id="my-marquee" style="">This is basic example of marquee</marquee>
```